# Illustrator: Need to have brush which is three dashed parallel line which can follow a curve

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

I want to create a brush (think this is the best approach) which is three dashed lines like this:

[image: dashed lines]

And I want to be able to place the lines along a path which curves, or around the edge of a circle.

I'm a bit new to Illustrator, and I know there is always more than one way to skin a cat. Can anyone illuminate me please as to the best approach? Is a brush the best way to go (and how to do this), or can you recommend something else please?

Answer (score 2):

I too am new to illustrator but I might be able to give you a simple solution.

1. You should be able to create three parallel lines by using your Line Segment tool or your pen tool. Don't forget to use the alignment tool for accuracy.
2. Make them dashed

Open your strokes palette and tick on dashed line

Since your dashes look closer together you can set it on 3pt as below

You should have something that looks like this.

[image: parallel dashed line]

3. Drag into brushes palette

From this point on, have your brushes palette open,
**Select these parallel lines and drag these into the brushes palette**

By doing so, you will get these Windows

[image: shortcut]

Once you hit OK, the pattern brush is now available in your brush palette and you can apply this to any strokes / curved you wish

Sorry if it looks a little messed up, couldn't post more than 2 links bec of my reputation.